# Obtain image path without IntentFilters inside a background service

Tags: android, image, service, path, filter

I have a rather tricky problem. I am working on a little project, which enables a user to "throw" content (images, audio files, videos) from his or her android phone to a computer screen. I use a Kinect in combination with the built in sensors of the phone to detect gestures which trigger the file exchange. 
I use UDP to upload files from or send requests to the phone.

I have been reading through the Intent developer guide, because it would be very nice to not have to write my own file browser to select the files I want to send. It would be perfect, if I could use existing software, such as the Gallery, to display Images on the phone and in addition, declare this image as selected and send it to the computer.

So, to make it more clear: Image on mnt storage on the phone --- detected gesture --> send the currently displayed image to the computer.

Now my question: 
How can I find the location of the currently displayed image? 
LogCat shows me this, when I display an image:

```
11-21 14:59:22.142: D/FullScreenView(20619): image index=0, uri=content://media/external/images/media/437, path=/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Loldroid/memebase/memes-inlove-cats-all-my-base-are-belong-to-you.jpg
```

Is there any possible way for me to receive this message in a service? My application will not have a userinterface, so I cannot use an IntentFilter as far as I understand.

Any input on if this is possible at all?

Best regards, 
Sticks